# I am trying to make a SOAP request with python and zeep

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xmlschema

I am trying to make a SOAP request with python and zeep, I need to add a soap:Header with the security (wsse:Security) and timestamp (wsu:Timestamp) labels

I do have this code:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse import UsernameToken
from zeep.wsse import utils
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create a SOAP client for the service
url = 'https://XXXXXXXXX/wsdlXXXXXX'
client = Client(url)

# Create a Object UsernameToken auth credentials
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
token = UsernameToken(username, password)

# Add object UsernameToken to the tag wsse:Security
security = client.get_element('wsse:Security')
security_value = security(namelist=[token])

# Create a object Timestamp with date an time (now)
timestamp = utils.Timestamp()
timestamp_created = datetime.utcnow()
timestamp_expires = timestamp_created + timedelta(minutes=10)
timestamp.created = timestamp_created
timestamp.expires = timestamp_expires

# Add the tag wsu:Timestamp to the hader SOAP
timestamp_value = timestamp.xml

# add the tags in header SOAP
header = client.service._binding.create_message_header()
header.append(security_value)
header.append(timestamp_value)

# Send request SOAP with header
result = client.service.addressTown(_soapheaders=[header], arg1='28001')
```

My error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 16, in <module>
    security = client.get_element('wsse:Security')
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\Eva Seguros\comparatupoliza\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\client.py", line 182, in get_element
    return self.wsdl.types.get_element(name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\Eva Seguros\comparatupoliza\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\schema.py", line 126, in get_element
    qname = self._create_qname(qname)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\Eva Seguros\comparatupoliza\venv\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\schema.py", line 265, in _create_qname
    raise ValueError("No namespace defined for the prefix %r" % prefix)
ValueError: No namespace defined for the prefix 'wsse'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing namespace for the `wsse` prefix, define it before using them in the get_element method.

Here what it would be below, dont forget to replace the `XXXXXXXXX/wsdlXXXXXX` with the actual URL of the WSDL and correct username and password for the `UsernameToken` object.

```
from zeep import Client, Settings
from zeep.wsse import UsernameToken
from zeep.wsse.utils import Timestamp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from lxml import etree

# Create a SOAP client for the service
url = 'https://XXXXXXXXX/wsdlXXXXXX'
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client(url, settings=settings)

# Define the required namespaces
client.wsdl.types.prefix_map['wsse'] = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
client.wsdl.types.prefix_map['wsu'] = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'

# Create a Object UsernameToken auth credentials
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
token = UsernameToken(username, password)

# Add object UsernameToken to the tag wsse:Security
security = client.get_element('wsse:Security')
security_value = security(namelist=[token])

# Create a object Timestamp with date an time (now)
timestamp = Timestamp()
timestamp_created = datetime.utcnow()
timestamp_expires = timestamp_created + timedelta(minutes=10)
timestamp.created = timestamp_created
timestamp.expires = timestamp_expires

# Add the tag wsu:Timestamp to the header SOAP
timestamp_value = timestamp.xml

# Create SOAP header
header = etree.Element("SOAP-ENV:Header", nsmap=client.wsdl.types.prefix_map)
header.append(security_value)
header.append(timestamp_value)

# Send request SOAP with header
result = client.service.addressTown(_soapheaders=[header], arg1='28001')
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried your example and it still returns the same error. ValueError: No namespace defined for the prefix 'wsse' (correctly replace url and credentials)